# Superclick menu not close when click inside

Tags: menu, superfish

I have input in submenu (https://github.com/joeldbirch/superclick), Is it possible hide element when clicked anywhere on the page, but I click inside submenu not close?

Comment: What you asked is not clear, if you are not comfortable writing in english, ask someone to proof-read it for you.

Comment: I mean, dropdown menu should not be closed if it is clicked inside. 
http://postimg.org/image/51qceiufz/
When i click input field, dropdown menu disappear
(its demo http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superclick/example.html)